# Apex Method to reset (or set to 0) fields values

Tags: apex, method

I would like a method to reset my values any time I need it. I can call it many times in my code, and I don't want to repeat all each time.

Like `dataUtils.reset()`

```
for (Sobject__c variable : lstOfObject) {
            
            // Reset amount fields of variable to 0
            variable.Montant_1   = 0;
            variable.Montant_2 = 0;
            variable.Montant_3 = 0;
            variable.Montant_4  = 0;
}
```

Comment: I would like a method to reset my values any time I need it... I can call it many times in my code, and I don't want to repeat all each time!
Like dataUtils.reset()....

Answer (score 1):

[class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm)

```
public List<SObject> resetValues(List<SObject> lstOfObject) {
    for (Sobject__c variable : lstOfObject) {    
            // Reset amount fields of variable to 0
            variable.put('Montant_1', 0);
            variable.put('Montant_2', 0);
            variable.put('Montant_3', 0);
            variable.put('Montant_4', 0);
    }
    return lstOfObject;
}
```

Comment: I would like a method to reset my values any time I need it... I can call it many times in my code, and I don't want to repeat all each time! Like dataUtils.reset()....

Comment: i've updated my answer